# Issue with tablayout in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am making dynamic tabs with dynamic list view within each tab fragment. The problem is when I am switching between two consecutive tabs the xml of previous tab is displayed but when I click non-consecutive tabs it's working fine. Don't know where the problem is so I am attaching my fragment class and HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity   {

    public ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private Toolbar toolbar;



    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private NonSwipeableViewPager viewPager;
    public ArrayList<String> mappingOfCategoryWithIndex = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<MenuItem> allMenuItemsList = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    ArrayList<MenuItemCategory> allMenuItemCategoryList = new ArrayList<MenuItemCategory>();

    //Getters
    public NonSwipeableViewPager getViewPager() {
        return viewPager;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getMappingOfCategoryWithIndex() {
        return mappingOfCategoryWithIndex;
    }
    public ArrayList<MenuItem> getAllMenuItemsList() {
        return allMenuItemsList;
    }
    public TabLayout getTabLayout() {
        return tabLayout;
    }
    public ArrayList<MenuItemCategory> getAllMenuItemCategoryList() {return allMenuItemCategoryList;}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home2);


        findViewById(R.id.tabs).bringToFront();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
// Getting All Menu Items



        GetAllMenuItems menuItemsReader = null;
        try {
            menuItemsReader = new GetAllMenuItems();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        allMenuItemsList = menuItemsReader.getMenuItemsList();

// Getting All Categories

        GetAllMenuItemCategories menuItemsCategoriesReader = null;
        try {
            menuItemsCategoriesReader = new GetAllMenuItemCategories();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        allMenuItemCategoryList = menuItemsCategoriesReader.getCategoryList();




//        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        viewPager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);



        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                //THIS!!
                if (viewPager != null) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {



        for (int i=0; i<allMenuItemCategoryList.size() ; i++){
            TextView tab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            tab.setText(allMenuItemCategoryList.get(i).Menu_Item_Category_Name);
            mappingOfCategoryWithIndex.add(i, allMenuItemCategoryList.get(i).Menu_Item_Category_Name) ;
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tab);
        }

//        int j = 0;
//        for (int i=0; i<allMenuItemCategoryList.size() ; i++){
//            TextView tab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
//            if(i%2==0){
//                tab.setText(allMenuItemCategoryList.get(j).Menu_Item_Category_Name);
//                j++;
//            }
//            else{
//                tab.setText("");
//
//            }
//            mappingOfCategoryWithIndex.add(i, allMenuItemCategoryList.get(i).Menu_Item_Category_Name) ;
//            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tab);
//
//
//
////            tab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, drawable.ic_launcher, 0, 0);
//
//
//
//        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        for (int i=0 ; i<allMenuItemCategoryList.size() ; i++) {
                adapter.addFrag(new TabCategory(), allMenuItemCategoryList.get(i).Menu_Item_Category_Name);
        }


//        int j=0;
//        for (int i=0 ; i<allMenuItemCategoryList.size()*2 ; i++) {
//            if (i % 2 == 0) {
//                adapter.addFrag(new TabCategory(), allMenuItemCategoryList.get(j).Menu_Item_Category_Name);
//                j++;
//            }
//            else{
//                adapter.addFrag(new dummyClass(), "");
//            }
//        }

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

//        private final List<String> tabPositionCategory = new ArrayList<>();


        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title ) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}

public class TabCategory extends Fragment{

    private TextView nameOfItem;


    HomeActivity2 activity;
    public HomeActivity2.ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    LinearLayout container1;

    public ArrayList<String> mappingOfCategoryWithIndex = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<MenuItem> allMenuItemsList1 = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    public ArrayList<MenuItemCategory> allCategoryList1 = new ArrayList<MenuItemCategory>();

    private NonSwipeableViewPager viewPager;

    private String selectedCategory;
    private int selectedCategoryId;

    private ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItemsOfSelectedCategory = new ArrayList<>();

    View rootView;

    public TabCategory() {



    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        activity = (HomeActivity2) getActivity();
        allMenuItemsList1 = activity.getAllMenuItemsList();

        mappingOfCategoryWithIndex =activity.getMappingOfCategoryWithIndex();

        tabLayout  = activity.getTabLayout();

        viewPager = activity.getViewPager();

        viewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners();
        adapter = activity.adapter;

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_category, container, false);



        menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.removeAll(menuItemsOfSelectedCategory);

        menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.clear();
        activity = (HomeActivity2) getActivity();
        allMenuItemsList1 = activity.getAllMenuItemsList();

        mappingOfCategoryWithIndex =activity.getMappingOfCategoryWithIndex();

        tabLayout  = activity.getTabLayout();

        viewPager = activity.getViewPager();

        adapter = activity.adapter;


        allCategoryList1 = activity.getAllMenuItemCategoryList();
        int tab_position=tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();

        selectedCategory = adapter.getPageTitle(tab_position).toString();
        System.out.println("Tab Category: " + selectedCategory );



        for (int i = 0 ; i<allMenuItemsList1.size();i++){
            if(allMenuItemsList1.get(i).getCategoryName().equals(selectedCategory)){
                menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.add(allMenuItemsList1.get(i));
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Size of Category Items: " + menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.size() );






        nameOfItem = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameofitem);

        System.out.println("Menu Size:"+ allMenuItemsList1.size());

        return rootView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        container1 = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container1);
        container1.removeAllViews();
        for (int i =0 ; i<menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.size();i++) {
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
            nameOfItem = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.nameofitem);
            nameOfItem.setText(menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.get(i).getName());

            container1.addView(addView);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        // not cleaning up.

        menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.removeAll(menuItemsOfSelectedCategory);

        menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.clear();
        container1.removeAllViews();
        container1.invalidate();
        System.out.println("destroyed!!!");
    }


}`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a complete code so that we can reproduce the problem. Consider the [MCVE question model](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is important to note that when a ViewPager page is selected, the selected page and one page on each side is loaded (The number of loaded pages can be increased using [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/refere‌​nce/android/support/‌​v4/view/ViewPager.ht‌​ml#setOffscreenPageL‌​imit(int)) with a minimum of 1. This is why when you select non-consecutive pages everything works properly, because all the calculations are done with this page from scratch, while when you select an adjacent page, the current page as well as the adjacent ones execute the same code.

Comment: So how to correct it?
setOffscreenPageLimit to 0?

Comment: @MohanadMohie I think u have identified the problem because when I set `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` then 2 consecutive previous and next pages are displayed.
Is there any solution to this problem?
I want to display only that fragment which is selected.

Comment: `setOffscreenPageLimit` can have a minimum value of 0, and increasing this value will not solve your problem, as your problem is that you initialize the Fragment with the current ViewPager's position, so when Frag1 is selected (`position = 0`), the `ViewPager` loads Frag2, but still with `position = 0`. I will have to check where the problem is in a few hours after I get home.

Comment: Okay please check it out. And let me know if you want to see any other part of the code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I put some mock data for testing, here's a working example (I modified your code, it still needs some enhancement but it works).

**HomeActivity2.java:**

```
public class HomeActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity   {

    public ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ArrayList<String> mappingOfCategoryWithIndex = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<MenuItem> allMenuItemsList = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    private ArrayList<MenuItemCategory> allMenuItemCategoryList = new ArrayList<MenuItemCategory>();

    //Getters
    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return viewPager;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getMappingOfCategoryWithIndex() {
        return mappingOfCategoryWithIndex;
    }
    public ArrayList<MenuItem> getAllMenuItemsList() {
        return allMenuItemsList;
    }
    public TabLayout getTabLayout() {
        return tabLayout;
    }
    public ArrayList<MenuItemCategory> getAllMenuItemCategoryList() {
        return allMenuItemCategoryList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home2);


        findViewById(R.id.tabs).bringToFront();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        allMenuItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
        allMenuItemsList.add(new MenuItem("Item 1", "Category 1"));
        allMenuItemsList.add(new MenuItem("Item 2", "Category 1"));
        allMenuItemsList.add(new MenuItem("Item 3", "Category 2"));
        allMenuItemsList.add(new MenuItem("Item 4", "Category 3"));
        allMenuItemsList.add(new MenuItem("Item 5", "Category 3"));

        allMenuItemCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        allMenuItemCategoryList.add(new MenuItemCategory("Category 1"));
        allMenuItemCategoryList.add(new MenuItemCategory("Category 2"));
        allMenuItemCategoryList.add(new MenuItemCategory("Category 3"));


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {

        for (int i=0; i<allMenuItemCategoryList.size() ; i++){
            TextView tab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            tab.setText(allMenuItemCategoryList.get(i).Menu_Item_Category_Name);
            mappingOfCategoryWithIndex.add(i, allMenuItemCategoryList.get(i).Menu_Item_Category_Name) ;
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tab);
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        for (int i=0 ; i<allMenuItemCategoryList.size() ; i++) {
            String category = allMenuItemCategoryList.get(i).Menu_Item_Category_Name;
            adapter.addFrag(TabCategory.getTabCategoryFragment(category), category);
        }

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title ) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**TabCategory.java:**

```
public class TabCategory extends Fragment {

    private static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
    private TextView nameOfItem;
    private HomeActivity2 activity;
    private LinearLayout container1;

    public ArrayList<String> mappingOfCategoryWithIndex = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<MenuItem> allMenuItemsList1 = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

    private String selectedCategory;

    private ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItemsOfSelectedCategory = new ArrayList<>();

    private View rootView;

    public TabCategory() {

    }

    public static TabCategory getTabCategoryFragment(String selectedCategory) {
        TabCategory tabCategory = new TabCategory();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(KEY_CATEGORY, selectedCategory);
        tabCategory.setArguments(args);
        return tabCategory;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        selectedCategory = getArguments().getString(KEY_CATEGORY);


        activity = (HomeActivity2) getActivity();

        allMenuItemsList1 = activity.getAllMenuItemsList();

        mappingOfCategoryWithIndex = activity.getMappingOfCategoryWithIndex();


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_category, container, false);
        container1 = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container1);
        return rootView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        container1.removeAllViews();
        menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < allMenuItemsList1.size(); i++) {
            if (allMenuItemsList1.get(i).getCategoryName().equals(selectedCategory)) {
                menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.add(allMenuItemsList1.get(i));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.size(); i++) {
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
            nameOfItem = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.nameofitem);
            nameOfItem.setText(menuItemsOfSelectedCategory.get(i).getName());

            container1.addView(addView);
        }

    }


}
```